# What is the best algorithm for putting N points into n intervals

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have N points in the interval [0,1] and I have already divided this unit interval into n sub-intervals, say [0,x1),[x1,x2),...,[xn-2,xn-1),[xn-1,1] Then I need to determine which sub-interval does each of these N points belong to. What is the best algorithm for completing this job? These sub-intervals do not distribute evenly but they are known. N is O(1 million), n is O(1 k).

Comment: Depends a bit on the relative size of N and n. Is one much larger than the other or are they approximately equal?

Comment: What does `which sub-interval does x belong to` mean? Find k such that xₖ≤x<xₖ₊₁? (I'd pose your question here rather than any other SE site. Please do not comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40298024/edit) your question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Comment: (I _presume_ the interval is _not_ divided evenly (xₘ₊₁-xₘ=c).)

Comment: @greybeard No they do not distribute evenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF points are not sorted, sort them by coordinate.

Do merging  (like merge algorithm in MergeSort) for point list with interval list.

Complexity  is `O(NlogN + N + n)`  (or `O(N + n)` if both list are sorted already)

Compare with @Mukul Varshney approach complexity `O(Nlogn)` and choose the best variant for your case

Answer (score 1):

Assuming lower bound of each interval i.e. 0,x1,x2,x3.... are in order, Preserve the 1st value(i.e. lower bounds) of the interval in an array, then use binary search to locate the index greater or less than the number n belongs to.

Comment: (It took me a second take to presume that you suggest putting the lower border of _each_ `interval in an array` - the 0,x₁,…,xₙ you mentioned before.)

Comment: Edited as per @greybeard comments